# text box value disappearing when page is refreshed using ajax set interval function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am reloading my page every 3 seconds using Ajax set interval function so the data from the database is dynamically updating without the need to click the refresh button, I have a text area which allows the user to enter values into the database, the problem I am having is that when the set interval function is executed the values that are in the text area disappears, is there any way to prevent this.

```
  setInterval(function(){
           $('#show_products').load('products.php');
       },3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it is impossible to understand what is happening :)

Ajax calls should not, by default, be clearing any inputs (you have to do this explicitly if it's the desired behaviour)

EDIT:

If you want to go from client to database, you need to do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'products.php',
  data: {
    product: $('#show_products').val()
  },
  success: function(response) {
    // Do something here, like show a confirmation message
  }
});
```

You will, of course, need to have a PHP script that takes the data and inserts it in the database,

Comment: So, $().load fetches data from the server and places it into the textarea. You want to do the opposite of that: you want to send data from the textarea to persist in the database, correct?

Comment: the products are select from the database every 3 seconds, and when this happens the text area is cleared which i do not want to happen

Answer (score 0):

Store the value of textbox in SESSION variable before updating values in database and then print it in textbox.